# .Net's XmlElement doesn't encode apos and quot?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

```
class C {
  [XmlElement("txt")]
  public string Txt {get; set;}
}
```

When serializing the above with `' " & < >`, the output is `' " &amp; &lt; &gt;`

Why isn't ' and " encoded to `&apos;` and `&quot;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes must be encoded within attributes, its not required when inside an XML element text.

Comment: You are right. I found this: http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#syntax. Thanks.